# Why my Geoprocessing tools was lost

Tags: qgis-processing, tools

[image]

How can I bring up my Geoprocessing tools again?

Comment: Uninstall QGIS and Reinstall it again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Plugins" > "Manage And Install Plugins"

Under "Installed" find the Processing plugin. If it's off then turn it back on, if it's on then turn it off and then back on.